# Python zipfile threading for use with progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar

I find myself coming to SO more and more lately. While trying to learn Python (by jumping right in and trying to port an application from C#), I've come across something that I had never heard of before: Threading. When I thought I had a basic understanding down, I tried converting the portion of the program that zips a directory full of files (and subdirectories). This is what I came up with so far - with help from a few sources I'll list at the end:

```
from Queue import Queue

import os
import gtk
import threading
import time
import zipfile

debug = True

class ProduceToQueue( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, threadName, queue, window, maximum, zipobj, dirPath ):
        threading.Thread.__init__( self, name = threadName )
        self.sharedObject = queue
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.zip = zipobj
        self.dirPath = dirPath
        self.window = window

        global debug

        if debug:
            print self.getName(), "got all params."

    def run( self ):
        if debug:
            print "Beginning zip."
        files = 0
        parentDir, dirToZip = os.path.split(self.dirPath)
        includeDirInZip = False
        #Little nested function to prepare the proper archive path
        def trimPath(path):
            archivePath = path.replace(parentDir, "", 1)
            if parentDir:
                archivePath = archivePath.replace(os.path.sep, "", 1)
            if not includeDirInZip:
                archivePath = archivePath.replace(dirToZip + os.path.sep, "", 1)
            return os.path.normcase(archivePath)
        for (archiveDirPath, dirNames, fileNames) in os.walk(self.dirPath):
            #if debug:
                #print "Walking path..."
            for fileName in fileNames:
                time.sleep( 0.001 )
                #if debug:
                    #print "After a small sleep, I'll start zipping."
                filePath = os.path.join(archiveDirPath, fileName)
                self.zip.write(filePath, trimPath(filePath))
                #if debug:
                    #print "File zipped - ",
                files = files + 1
                #if debug:
                    #print "I now have ", files, " files in the zip."
                self.sharedObject.put( files )
            #Make sure we get empty directories as well
            if not fileNames and not dirNames:
                zipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(trimPath(archiveDirPath) + "/")
                #some web sites suggest doing
                #zipInfo.external_attr = 16
                #or
                #zipInfo.external_attr = 48
                #Here to allow for inserting an empty directory.  Still TBD/TODO.
                outFile.writestr(zipInfo, "")

class ConsumeFromQueue( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, threadName, queue, window, maximum ):
        threading.Thread.__init__( self, name = threadName )
        self.sharedObject = queue
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.window = window

        global debug

        if debug:
            print self.getName(), "got all params."

    def run( self ):
        print "Beginning progress bar update."
        for i in range( self.maximum ):
            time.sleep( 0.001 )
            #if debug:
                #print "After a small sleep, I'll get cracking on those numbers."
            current = self.sharedObject.get()
            fraction = current / float(self.maximum)
            self.window.progress_bar.set_fraction(fraction)
            #if debug:
                #print "Progress bar updated."

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        vb = gtk.VBox()
        self.add(vb)
        self.progress_bar = gtk.ProgressBar()
        vb.pack_start(self.progress_bar)
        b = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_OK)
        vb.pack_start(b)
        b.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        b2 = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_CLOSE)
        vb.pack_start(b2)
        b2.connect('clicked', self.on_close_clicked)
        self.show_all()

        global debug

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        folder_to_zip = "/home/user/folder/with/lotsoffiles"
        file_count = sum((len(f) + len(d) for _, d, f in os.walk(folder_to_zip)))
        outFile = zipfile.ZipFile("/home/user/multithreadziptest.zip", "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        queue = Queue()

        producer = ProduceToQueue("Zipper", queue, self, file_count, outFile, folder_to_zip)
        consumer = ConsumeFromQueue("ProgressBar", queue, self, file_count)

        producer.start()
        consumer.start()

        producer.join()
        consumer.join()

        outFile.close()

        if debug:
            print "Done!"

    def on_close_clicked(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

w = MainWindow()
gtk.main()
```

Problem with this is after about 7,000 files the program locks up and I have to force quit it. I haven't tried with any less files than that, but I think it would probably have the same problem. Also, the progress bar does not update. I know it's messy (programming style-wise with mixed underscored and CamelCase, and general noobish mistakes), but I can't think of any reason for it not to work.

Here's where I got most of this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/File/Multithreadingzipfile.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0340__Thread/Multiplethreadsproducingconsumingvalues.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the `file_count` is wrong and the consumer waits forever for another object to `.get`. Change the line to `current = self.sharedObject.get(timeout=5)` and if thats the case it should throw an error at the end.

Also, yes there are many issues with your code -- for example when you use GTK you don't want your own threads at all.

GTK has it's own threading library that is safe to use with gtks main loop. See pages like http://www.pardon-sleeuwaegen.be/antoon/python/page0.html or google for "gtk threading"

Comment: `>for example when you use GTK you don't want your own threads at all.`

What do you mean by this? Every other tutorial I've seen on threading with GTK does it like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and see if I can't figure this thing out.